# Flask wtforms: validate_on_submit() returns true every time

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms

I'm new to programming and am wondering why validate_on_submit() returns True every time even if the form is not filled. I am trying to build a duplicate of a social website(facebook, twitter) and am trying to implement a way to comment, reply, and like a post. However, everytime I "like" a post or comment, a duplicate of the comment is added into the database.

Here's my code:

in forms.py:

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    content = TextAreaField("Content", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Post")

class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    content = TextAreaField("Comment_content", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Comment")

class ReplyForm(FlaskForm):
    content = TextAreaField("Reply_content", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Reply")
```

in routes.py:

```py
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def post(post_id):
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    reply_form = ReplyForm()
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    image_file = url_for("static", filename="profile_pic" + current_user.image_file)
    comments = Post_comment.query.order_by(Post_comment.date_commented.desc()).filter_by(post_id=post_id)
    print(comment_form.validate_on_submit)
    if "post_like" in request.form:
        user_likes_post(request.form["post_like"])
    elif "comment_like" in request.form:
        user_likes_comment(request.form["comment_like"])
    elif "reply_like" in request.form:
        user_likes_reply(request.form["reply_like"])
    if comment_form.validate_on_submit:
        comment = Post_comment(content=comment_form.content.data, comment_author=current_user, post=post)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
    elif reply_form.validate_on_submit:
        reply = Comment_reply(content=reply_form.content.data, reply_author=current_user)
        db.session.add(reply)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("post.html", post=post, comment_form=comment_form, reply_form=reply_form, image_file=image_file, comments=comments)
```

in post.html:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div id="post">
    <div id="post_desc">
        <img src="{{ image_file }}">
        <a>{{ post.author.username }}</a>
        {{ post.date_posted }}
    </div>   
    <div id="post_content">
        {{ post.content }}  
    </div>   
    <div>{{ post.like_count }}</div>
    <form method="POST">
        <button name="post_like" type="submit" value="{{ post.id }}" >like</button>  

        <button name="comment" type="button" href="#" >comment</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ comment_form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ comment_form.csrf_token }}
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                {% if comment_form.content.errors %}
                    {{ comment_form.content() }}
                    <div>
                        {% for error in comment_form.content.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ comment_form.content() }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>        
        <div>
            {{ comment_form.submit() }}
        </div>
    </form>
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div id="comment">
        <div id="comment_desc">
            <img src="{{ image_file }}">
            <a>{{ comment.comment_author.username }}</a>
            {{ comment.date_posted }}
        </div>   
        <div id="comment_content">
            {{ comment.content }}  
        </div>   
        <div>{{ comment.like_count }}</div>
        <form method="POST">
            <button name="comment_like" type="submit" value="{{ comment.id }}" >like</button>  
        </form>
    </div>
        <div>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {{ reply_form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ reply_form.csrf_token }}
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        {% if reply_form.content.errors %}
                            {{ reply_form.content() }}
                            <div>
                                {% for error in reply_form.content.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ reply_form.content() }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>        
                <div>
                    {{ reply_form.submit() }}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        {% for reply in comment.replies %}
            <div id="reply">
                <div id="reply_desc">
                    <img src="{{ image_file }}">
                    <a>{{ reply.reply_author.username }}</a>
                    {{ reply.date_posted }}
                </div>   
                <div id="reply_content">
                    {{ reply.content }}  
                </div>   
                <div>{{ reply.like_count }}</div>
                <form method="POST">
                    <button name="reply_like" type="submit" value="{{ reply.id }}" >like</button>  
                </form>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What I think is happening here is that when I "like" the post, comment, or reply, a POST request is sent but I am not sure why validate_on_submit() returns true for it to pass the if statement and add the entry to the database even when there is the Datarequired() validator.

Apologies if my code is quite messy, I'm new to programming and need some time to learn best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might have syntax issues,

This is what you have:

```
if comment_form.validate_on_submit:
```

This is how the [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#validating-forms) says it should be used:

```
if comment_form.validate_on_submit():
```

[image]

Hope that helps! :D

Comment: omg now I feel dumb for wasting so much time over a syntax error haha